# Creating an executable .jar file for an application that uses Jframes?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jframe

I am attempting to create an executable .jar file in Eclipse, to run an application which uses JFrames. I can run other .jar files that do not use JFrames, but for this application, the file does nothing when double clicked. There are no errors in the code, and it runs fine inside eclipse.

It appears to be an error with reading in a text file from inside a folder, it works fine inside eclipse, but not inside the jar file.

Comment: Try running from the command line to see if there is any error output

Comment: Thanks, a few errors came up that were not showing in eclipse.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include them, if you'd like

Comment: Have you included in that file in your jar? What does your reading file code look like?

Comment: public void openFile(){
    
       try{
       m = new Scanner(new File("Map//Map.txt"));
       }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("error loading map");
       }
    }

Comment: It seems to work in eclipse, but not inside the jar file.